# Updating Vega-lite legend color based on color condition

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am having trouble getting the legend coloring to update with the value `red` which is not in the color scale range, but rather is set through a condition. Is it possible to tell the legend to respect the `condition` clause rather than just always showing the color from the scale range (`green, yellow, orange`)?

```
"color": {
          "field": "Symbol",
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.Symbol == 'RedSymbol'",
            "value": "red"
          },
          "scale": {
             "range": [
                   "green",
                   "yellow",
                   "orange"
                      ]
                   }
         },
```